# Make sure PrefPane is always running?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstimer

I'm building a PrefPane that monitors the time and then does an action when it passes a certain time.

I've got this working with a simple NSTimer instance that runs every second:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(checkTime)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

The issue is that this timer is not always guaranteed to be running. If I open the PrefPane, it is but after I close it, there's no guarantee. What should the correct approach be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to start a separate process and keep your timer in that process.

Comment: In other words a preference pane only runs when it is visible. Your preference pane would need to launch a separate process that it can monitor when it is visible.